# blockchain oracles to communicate with external api via smart contracts?

Tags: solidity, ether, dapp-development, oracles

Is there is any other oracles other than provable or oraclize to communicate with external api via smart contract.

Comment: Yes, you have ChainLink for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Chainlink](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data)
2. [Tellor](https://tellor.io/)
3. [Bandchain](https://docs.bandchain.org/)

Please note, you can get started with a single centralized way to pull data from an API, but for your contract to be decentralized you'd want to pull data from multiple sources via multiple nodes.

You can, for example, pull data from a single Chainlink node just to start developing, however for a production grade system you'd want to pull data from a network of nodes.

Here is a complete example of pulling data from a single chainlink node. This job returns a Uint256. For different data types to return, look at the [chainlink adapters](https://docs.chain.link/docs/adapters).

To call the `requestEthereumPrice` funciton, you have to pick an oracle and a job. You could use the following [linkpool](https://www.linkpool.io/) oracle/job.

`address ORACLE = 0x83F00b902cbf06E316C95F51cbEeD9D2572a349a;`

`string constant JOB = "c179a8180e034cf5a341488406c32827";`

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.4/ChainlinkClient.sol";

// MyContract inherits the ChainlinkClient contract to gain the
// functionality of creating Chainlink requests
contract ChainlinkExample is ChainlinkClient {
  // Stores the answer from the Chainlink oracle
  uint256 public currentPrice;
  address public owner;

  constructor() public {
    // Set the address for the LINK token for the network
    setPublicChainlinkToken();
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  // Creates a Chainlink request with the uint256 multiplier job
  function requestEthereumPrice(address _oracle, bytes32 _jobId, uint256 _payment) 
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    // newRequest takes a JobID, a callback address, and callback function as input
    Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(_jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
    // Adds a URL with the key "get" to the request parameters
    req.add("get", "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=USD");
    // Uses input param (dot-delimited string) as the "path" in the request parameters
    req.add("path", "USD");
    // Adds an integer with the key "times" to the request parameters
    req.addInt("times", 100);
    // Sends the request with the amount of payment specified to the oracle
    sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, _payment);
  }

  // fulfill receives a uint256 data type
  function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _price)
    public
    // Use recordChainlinkFulfillment to ensure only the requesting oracle can fulfill
    recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId)
  {
    currentPrice = _price;
  }
  
  // cancelRequest allows the owner to cancel an unfulfilled request
  function cancelRequest(
    bytes32 _requestId,
    uint256 _payment,
    bytes4 _callbackFunctionId,
    uint256 _expiration
  )
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    cancelChainlinkRequest(_requestId, _payment, _callbackFunctionId, _expiration);
  }

  
  // withdrawLink allows the owner to withdraw any extra LINK on the contract
  function withdrawLink()
    public
    onlyOwner
  {
    LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
    require(link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))), "Unable to transfer");
  }
  
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }
}
```